# php/html5 playlist using glob()

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using the php glob() to get all the song's in the song folder 
then use the array_rand to get a random song then use a foreach loop to loop the 
songs.Any way I can get this to work

```
    <!DOC TYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>ymp</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

    </head>
     <body>
     <h1>YMP RADIO</h1>
     <?php require ("dropmenu.html"); ?>




      <?php     
        $music = glob("songs/*");  // get all files in the music directory
        shuffle($music);
        foreach ($music as $song){           // try and loop a random songs

        }
         var_dump($song)
       ?>
         <audio id="player" src="<?php  $song ?>" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
         <audio id="player" src="<?php  $song ?>" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
       <br /><br /><br />
        <div> 
        <table border="1px" >
        <tr>

        <td class="tdpage" >
        <img src="ymplogo5.jpg" alt=""  />
        <p><button  class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button>
       <button     class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">Pause</button>
         <button     class="botton";   onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume+=0.1">Volume up </button>
          <button     class="botton";          onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume-=0.1">Volume down</button>

     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>   
     </div> 

     <br /><br /><br />
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: you CAN get this to work? great! thanks for sharing! but seriously, what's the problem? be more specific about what's [not] working

Comment: Firstly, change this `<!DOC TYPE HTML>` no space between `DOC` and `TYPE`

Comment: I made something like this but as a CLI in NodeJS: [glob-playlist (glop)](https://github.com/laggingreflex/glob-playlist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i believe you want to loop though them all in random order, in that case use shuffle()

```
$music = glob("songs/");  // get all files in the music directory
shuffle($music);

      foreach ($music as $song){           
//code
       }
```

Comment: Hello I tried what you said above i used the var_dump($song) to soo the value of $song it looks like its being set now where it was not before, and added the mime type to audio and tag and added one audio tag for mp3 and ogg but still cant get it to play

Answer (score 0):

Your current glob pattern is just matching a directory.

To make to match all files in the directory, use the '*' wildcard character.

```
$music=glob("songs/*");
```